# VB.Net Code in class and WithEvents issue

Tags: vb.net, class

I've created a VB.Net application which consists of a form and a series of classes.  One class (GUI) contains all of the routines that handle the logic associated with the controls on my form.  These controls are placed at design time.

I've having a problem with a couple of the timers on the form.  They are declared in the GUI class thus:

```
Private WithEvents timerScreenUpdate As Timer
Private WithEvents timerDebug As Timer
```

but I'm getting an error in this line:

```
Private Sub timerScreenUpdate_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles timerScreenUpdate.Tick
```

The error is "Event 'Tick' cannot be found".  I'm getting the same error for the other timer.

It's probably related but I'm also getting a similar error in this line:

```
Private Sub Monitor_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
```

which is "Event 'FormClosing' cannot be found".

How can I make these events visible to my class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the reference and the Namespace-Import of `System.Windows.Forms` is available in your project respectively class file.

Without it, VB will use a Timer from the namespace `System.Timers` which you don't want to use in your case.

Comment: Excellent, adding System.Windows.Forms like this Private WithEvents timerScreenUpdate As System.Windows.Forms.Timer has got rid of the the timer errors.  Thank you.  I just need to figure out the FormClosing error and I'm done !

Comment: Check the designer code file of your form whether your form derives from the type Form ('Inherits Form' at the top of the file). I think it does but the type Form could not be resolved. Make sure theres 'Imports System.Windows.Forms' in the designer code file as well.